# Scala implicit macros: Filter type members (tpe.decls) by sub-type

Tags: scala, macros

Let's say I have a simple impicit macro that gives me back a `weakTypeSymbol`:

```
@macrocompat.bundle
class ExampleMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  def macroImpl[T : WeakTypeTag]: Tree = {
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val subType = typeOf[SomeType].typeSymbol
    val target = tpe.decls.collect {
      case tp if tp.typeSignature.typeSymbol == subType => tp
    } 
    ...
  }
}
```

That's a very rudimentary version of it, in short I need inner members of `T` that satisfy a particular sub-typing relationship. It looks like the types on the inner members however have not been evaluated at this time, because `tp.typeSignature.typeSymbol` is `<none>`.

Is there a known way of doing this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable with an API similar to reflection:

```
    class TestMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
      import c.universe._
      def filterMembers[
        T : WeakTypeTag,
        Filter : TypeTag
      ]: List[Symbol] = {
        val tpe = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.typeSignature

        (for {
          baseClass <- tpe.baseClasses.reverse
          symbol <- baseClass.typeSignature.members.sorted
          if symbol.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Filter]
        } yield symbol)(collection.breakOut)
      }
    }
```